# How to boost ranking for NGrams by their matched length

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm getting to grips with Elasticsearch and have a small dataset with a number of terms with shared Ngrams.

For example currently Elasticsearch is ranking

`United Kingdom > Agriculture > Grains > Feed Wheat > Ex-Farm`

as a better match for "Meat" than

`United Kingdom > Agriculture > Livestock & Meat > Lamb > Deadweight`

I believe that if I can get ES to consider the length of the matched Ngram into it's score, then this problem will mostly resolve itself.

I've spent a lot of time googling for any hints but nothing has come up so far.

I've defined my Ngram filter using python's elasticsearch-dsl

```
ngram_filter = token_filter(
    'ngram_filter',
    type='ngram',
    min_gram=3,
    max_gram=10,
)

ngram_analyzer = analyzer(
    'ngram_analyzer',
    type='custom',
    tokenizer='whitespace',
    filter=[
        'lowercase',
        ngram_filter
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After walking away for a bit and thinking about it, I decided to break the NGram analyzers into different fields, separated by length. This way I could manually boost longer NGram matches. I think I was trying to do too much with a single field.

I'm not programmatically building them up using django-elasticsearch-dsl like so.

```
ngram_analyzers = {
    f'{i}ngram': fields.TextField(
        analyzer=analyzer(
            f'{i}ngram_analyzer',
            type='custom',
            tokenizer='whitespace',
            filter=[
                'lowercase',
                token_filter(
                    f'{i}ngram_filter',
                    type='ngram',
                    min_gram=i,
                    max_gram=i
                )
            ]
        )
    ) for i in range(3, 11)
}

ngram_analyzers.update({
            'stemmed': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='english',
            )
        })
```

Comment: In your example you can also use a subfield with a standard analyzer and a higher boost on this field.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel I did end up doing that as the base field with subfields of various length ngrams, in addition to a stemming field and then taking advantage of a multi_match with most_fields to get a really good blend of matches. I've not since needed to boost a single field artificially. My only issue now is when to use synonyms for best effect without introducing false corrolation